# How to keep specific words together on one line?

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I have a sample paragraph and I am adding chunk values into :

```
p.add(firstname);
p.add(lastname);
p.add(phone);
p.add(login);
```

Is it possible to detect position of chunk on page ?

For example, firstname and lastname are added on paragraph and the following string (phone) exceed the middle of the page, I add

```
Chunk.NEWLINE
```

and go to the new line.

Comment: iText does not do any layouting before the paragraph is actually drawn on the page, e.g. when you add it to a document. Before that notions like *exceed the middle of the page* make no sense anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve what you want. Replace all the spaces where you don't want a line break with `\u00a0`. This way, you don't have to check positions etc. (That would only be possible if you calculate the width of every `String` snippet.)

For instance, if you do this:

```
p.add("Valeriane\u0060Valerius 012\u0060345\u006067\u006089 valerianelogin");
```

The `String` can only be split on two places (unless you use so many non-breaking spaces that you take so much space that the part you don't want to break doesn't even fit a line).

Comment: Thank you Bruno for your response, but it can't help me. I am trying to draw a rectangle in paragraph on the same line that paragraph text. My rectangle have fixed width (half of page),. When I set rectangle on the page I need to know what is current position for setting (or not) newline. You already helped me for rectangle draw :) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837498/table-on-same-line/32837855)

Comment: You have page events to get those coordinates. You already know this, because you already posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869808/itextpdf-rectangle-modify-width) too. If it's about paragraphs, you can use the paragraph related page events to draw the rectangle around the paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I am trying to draw a rectangle arround differents chunks of paragraph. So I can to have a paragraph completed by chunks on all over the page. For example, for each phoneNumber I draw a rectangle.

Comment: I tried add newline on document in onGenericTag but it throws ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Could you provide a short, standalone example we can use to reproduce this problem? Such an error can be thrown when you're trying to change an array when you're still reading it. If that's the case, the exception is unrelated to the `onGenericTag()` method, but it could be related to changing the `Rectangle` (see your other question). A rectangle is stored as an array of two or four values.